# array key value pair at a specified point in array

Tags: php

I have an associative array , i would like to add some more  key and values

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/31/2011
        )
     [1] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 87
            [TYPE] => something
            [DATE] => 3/28/2011


          )
     [2] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/2/2011


          )

)
```

In Above array i want to add another key named STATUS and value before DATE 
so that  finally iget

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [STATUS] => waiting
            [DATE] => 3/31/2011
        )
}
```

canPlease give me proper direction

Comment: It's just an array, it's not rocket science: `$array[0]['STATUS'] = 'waiting'`

Comment: I have something like $arr2[] = $row; which holds the array,how to add it dynamically to it is my question

Comment: well, what did you try so far that failed?

Comment: i use  foreach($arr2 as $key => $value) 
            {
            
   $arr2[$key]['Status'] = 'waiting'; But it appends to last
}

Comment: It appends to the last after date ,i need it after type ...

Comment: do you actually MAKE that array? Then insert `'status' => null`at creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = Array(
          0 => Array('NUMBER' => 67, 'TYPE' => Other, 'DATE' => '3/32/2011'),
          1 => Array('NUMBER' => 87, 'TYPE' => something, 'DATE' => '3/28/2011'),
          2 => Array('NUMBER' => 67, 'TYPE' => Other, 'DATE' => '3/2/2011')
       );

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   $arr[$key] = array_slice($value, 0, 2) + 
                array('Status' => 'waiting') + 
                array_slice($value, -1);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

gives the following array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["NUMBER"]=>
    int(67)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(5) "Other"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(7) "waiting"
    ["DATE"]=>
    string(9) "3/32/2011"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["NUMBER"]=>
    int(87)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(9) "something"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(7) "waiting"
    ["DATE"]=>
    string(9) "3/28/2011"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["NUMBER"]=>
    int(67)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(5) "Other"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(7) "waiting"
    ["DATE"]=>
    string(8) "3/2/2011"
  }
}
```